# intersection of two irreducible spaces not irreducible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y_1,Y_2$ be two distinct irreducible subsets with none containing the other. Then it seems to me that $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ need not be irreducible.
Is that right?

Two remarks from which i draw my intuition:

Remark 1: If we let $Y_1,Y_2$ be irreducible sets in the Zariski topology of $\mathbb{A}^n$, then their vanishing ideal is the radical of the sum of two prime ideals, i.e. $\sqrt{I(Y_1)+I(Y_2)}$, which does not seem to be prime in general.

Remark 2: Intuitively, it seems to me quite possible that an irreducible space would contain a reducible subspace.

Comment: Try intersecting a parabola with a line in general position.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: In two dimensions i will just get two points and these two points are a reducible space because they are the union of one with the other. Nice. I can accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make my comment an answer: try intersecting a parabola with a line in general position.